# How possibly change widget in not parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

When i clicking on button i need change activity and text in TextView which belong this activity, i try do it like this:

in MyActivity:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.MondayButton:
        NameDiscipline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Discipline8);
        NameDiscipline.setText("Some Text");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SheduleForTheDayActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

in OtherActivity.xml:

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Discipline8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

and when i click on MondayButton my app crashing. Without lines

```
NameDiscipline = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Discipline8);
            NameDiscipline.setText("Some Text");
```

code work correctly.

Comment: The `Discipline8` `TextView` is not part of the content view of `MyActivity`, yet you're trying to access it. I'm guessing your call to `findViewById` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in the Activity class with Discipline8. Have the onReceive method change the text. Then, in MyActivity, call

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                     .sendBroadcast(new IntentFilter("some string to use as action"));
```